# why is div included in sister-div?

Tags: css

I don't understand why the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/zHH4D/
doesn't show the "to the right" outside the red area and to the right,
but inside the red block?!

I can put the div outside the parent div and this kind of works but it just doesn't make sense to me.

Where am i thinking wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo:

```
<div style="width:340px;float:left;background-color:#f00;">
    <div>above ok</<div> <!-- TYPO -->
    <div>under ok</div>
</div>
```

This causes the browser to interpret your markup as best as it can, which results in this (copied from Chrome inspector):

```
<div style="width:340px;float:left;background-color:#f00;">
    <div>above ok<!--<div-->
    <div>under ok</div>
</div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    to the right?
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/zHH4D/1/):

```
<div style="width:340px;float:left;background-color:#f00;">
    <div>above ok</div> <!-- Notice the closing div tag -->
    <div>under ok</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A simple typo.. But you gave an awesome explanation!! Great. Keep it up.